# passing flags to bash script via ssh key

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, key

So lets say I have ClientA and ServerB set up and I have ServerB set up to run a backup script. Now for reasons which are irrelevant to the issue at hand, the backup script needs to run several bash scripts on ClientA. Now for security reasons, I have a "backup" user set up on ClientA and a key pair allowing ServerB to log into ClientA as this "backup" user. However I would like to take this a step further and only allow the key to work on a single script.

Here is that key:

```
command="/backup.sh",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa A......
```

My problem is that I run the script on ClientA several times and each time I use a number of different flags. However, I can not seem to pass these flags through the SSH key.

So lets say I try and run the following:

```
$ ssh backup@ClientA "/backup.sh -b"
```

This will not pass the -b flag through because of the key I have set up on ClientA. Is there a way to allow the flag to be passed through the ssh key I have set up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` for this sort of thing.

> SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND This variable contains the original command line if a forced command is executed.  It can be used to extract the original arguments

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I have done some googling and its not looking quite as simple as you say.

Comment: In the environment of the forced command process you should have an `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable. That variable should contain the contents of the originally requested command. `/backup.sh -b` in your example. You should be able to use that to parse out the original arguments.